# Separate Survey results into developers and non-developers

Tags: feature-request, survey-2018

You break down the responses, where appropriate, into 2 groups:

1. All
2. Developers

On the surface, this is fine.
However, since the vast majority of the responders are developers, both graphs look almost the same.

To really see a difference, you can't put the largest piece on both sides.

I would encourage you to Investigate

1. != Developers
2. == Developers

We may be able to learn from the difference, but only if we can SEE it.

Comment: Isn't it All and *Professional* developers?

Answer (score 4):

The two main categories we have are

- All respondents
- Professional developers

The people who don't fall into the professional developer category are people who said they code for open source or as a hobby but not part of their jobs. Those people are part of the Stack Overflow community so we definitely wanted to include them in the survey, but obviously they are dwarfed in number by people who are professional developers.

I like your idea of showing this more explicitly, at least for some relevant sections, to talk about people who code but not as part of their job. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I THINK we are in agreement. Putting "Developers" in both groups overwhelms  the smaller data set. Can't tell anything about them.
Is this something that can be changed in the current report, or is that written in stone?